# How can I participate in NNTP newsgroups over a (HTTP) proxy?

Tags: proxy, newsgroups, nntp

My company restricts access to the outside via an (HTTP) proxy.

My Firefox settings for the proxy are working (proxy address + port as well as "use this proxy server for all protocols"). However, if I use the same settings for the proxy in Thunderbird I cannot access any NNTP groups. (I use one unsecured server over port 119 and one secured server (eternal-september.org) over port 563 -- both do not work via this proxy.

What can I do to read+post text NNTP messages? (I would like to avoid Google Groups as it doesn't work properly for some moderated newsgroups.)

Oh, and note that all of the NG I access are actually work related :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of www-nntp gateways that allow nntp over a web interface

example:
http://www.nntp.hk/web/

you can easily roll out your own if you use the perl Net::NNTP interface which in my opinion is very easy to use.

Comment: Thanks. It seems rather more inconvenient than using a dedicated client though. Do you know of any such (free or commercial) gateway that would provide me with a user login and store read messages/state server side?

Comment: i haven't seen one so far. However, how about you script a customised CSS to be applied onto the site, with read links being shown e.g. in gray... read here on how to do that in firefox.. http://coreygilmore.com/blog/2008/10/23/per-site-custom-css-in-firefox/

Answer (score -1):

this server support HTTP to read/post in usenet
http://gall.mine.nu/cgi-bin/dnewsweb.exe